# Sass Folders Outputing to CSS Folder

Tags: css, sass

I'm having this rather annoying trouble that I'm having some issues understanding when my Sass compiles.

I have a SCSS folder that compiles to a CSS folder in the root of my site, but in my SCSS folder I have individual folders for layout, utilities, etc.

The issue I am having is within my SCSS structure I have a vendors folder that houses everything from Bootstrap Grid, Font Awesome, etc. To keep the structure of the vendors folder neat and tidy I like to keep each vendor add on in a seperate folder. I use the following watch command:

`sass --watch scss:css`

Here's the file structure where `...` is the files within the folder.

```
project-name/
├── scss/
│   └── style.scss
└── vendors/
    ├── bootstrap-grid
    │   └── ...
    └── fontawesome
        └── ...
```

The issue I have when compiling to the CSS folder, the vendors folder and its contents are being compiled to the CSS folder:

```
project-name/
├── css/
│   └── style.css
└── vendors/
    ├── bootstrap-grid
    │   └── ...
    └── fontawesome
        └── ...
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try using this code: `sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css`

Comment: You're a legend, this works! Thanks so much 

Comment: @flying-dev Please mark manish's answer as accepted so everyone knows this is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this command: 
`sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css`